# Duplicate Entry error for Unique key on Update Yii Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am facing the following error while trying to update the record in my table:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'ABCD1111P' for key 'pan_UNIQUE'
```

Table has column i.e. "pan" which has unique key assigned.

And following is my code in controller:

```
$model->pan = $_POST['CustomerBasics']['pan'];
$model->cell = $_POST['CustomerBasics']['cell'];
$model->gender = $_POST['PersonalDetails']['gender'];

$valid = $model->validate();
            print_r($model->getErrors());
            if ($valid) {
                $model->update();
                $personal_details_id = $model->personal_details_id;
            }
```

And in Model:

```
array('pan', 'unique', 'on' => 'insert', 'message' => '{attribute}:{value} already exists!'),
```

What is the issue? Where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why -ve ? Can anybody please explain?

Comment: can you show how many record in table group by pan ? `select * from table group by pan` ; My concerns is that when updating pan='pan2' if pan2 already exists it will fail obviously.

Comment: unfortunately its habit of some to down-vote without any reason and explanation.

Answer (score 8):

since you have said that @Daneil Vaquero's solution is not working.However its working as follow.

**UserController Update action**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
            $model->username='admin';

            if( $model->validate() && $model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            else
                print_r($model->getErrors());
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

**User model rules() method**

```
    public function rules()
        {
         array('username', 'unique', 'on' => 'insert,update', 'message' => '{attribute}:{value} already exists!'),
            );
        }
```

See I  manually set username to `admin` , except `admin` user , validation will fail , as expected and pointed by others.

You application should work fine except you have to change `'on' => 'insert'` to `'on' => 'insert,update'`, in model rules settings

Answer (score 0):

You are specified the rule on `insert` scenario. if you want the rule applied for all scenarios like `update`, have to change the rule as this:

`array('pan', 'unique', 'message' => '{attribute}:{value} already exists!'),`

Or if you want the rule applied on `insert & update` scenarios setting rule as this:

`array('pan', 'unique', 'on' => 'insert,update', 'message' => '{attribute}:{value} already exists!'),`

Comment: Thanks but I tried both scenario but still its showing unique key error. Actually in case of update it should have to accept that because I am not updating PAN card there.

Answer (score 0):

**Model** rules() :

```
array('pan', 'unique'),
```

**Controller** create or update action :

```
   if (isset($_POST['Pan'])) {
         $model->attributes = $_POST['Pan'];
         if ($model->save()) {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'PAN Created/Updated');
                $this->redirect(array('update', 'id' => $model->id));
         }
   }

   $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
   ));
```

If not validate automaticly load 'create' view with the error message.

Comment: You are right but my case is slight different here I am first inserting data in database which is working correctly after that I am rendering it into the update page where I am displaying all the fields and user can update whatever the changes he wants. Suppose user not wants to change PAN card then he'll leave that field. So in that case table should have to accept that but its showing unique key error which is not correct.

Comment: I use the above code ever and works perfectly. When i update the $model->save() control the '$model->isNewRecord' and if update the 'unique' field is validated with other records but not with himself ...

Comment: I think this should be working as expected, I tested and this working